# In thermodynamic limit, how is $\frac{V}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} k= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{3} r \mathrm{~d}^{3} \boldsymbol{P}}{h^{3}}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, identical-particles

In the book *Intro. Statistical Physics* by K.Huang, on page 106, it is given that

> Because of indistinguishability; the $N$ -body wave function is labelled by the set $\left\{\alpha_{1}, \cdots, \alpha_{N}\right\}$, in which the ordering of the set is irrelevant. [...]The number $n_{\alpha}$ is called the occupation number of the single-particle state $\alpha_{1}$ with the allowed values
> For an $N$ -particle system, they satisfy the condition
> $$
> \sum_{\alpha} n_{\alpha}=N
> $$
> [...]
> For free particles, it is convenient to choose the single-particle functions to be plane waves. The label $\alpha$ corresponds to the wave vector $\mathbf{k}$ :
> [...]
> In the thernodynanic limit, we can replace the sum over plane-wave states by an integral:
> $$
> \sum_{k} \rightarrow \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} k=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{3} r \mathrm{~d}^{3} \boldsymbol{P}}{h^{3}}
> $$

I got everything except how does the equality $\frac{V}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} k= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{3} r \mathrm{~d}^{3} \boldsymbol{P}}{h^{3}}$.

Where does this equality come from?

Comment: Be careful. Huang's way of writing the formula is misleading. The delicate point is not the change of variables from wavevectors to momenta, but the passage from a sum over a discrete sum over a finite and regular grid of points representing plane-wave states of a finite system (depending on the boundaries)  to an integral over a continuous wavenumber in an infinite system (without boundaries). In the thermodynamic limited the formula is meaningless because it is equivalent to $\infty=\infty$.

Comment: @GiorgioP I got your point, but a slight remark to your last point: mathematically speaking the fact that both sides of an equation are $\infty$ doesn't make the equality invalid.

Comment: I did not write that it would be invalid. It would be as useful as saying that $f'(x)\Delta x$ and $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$ both go to zero for $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$. One can only get the information that the first derivative is not diverging as fast as $1/\Delta x^a$ for $a\geq 0$, but it is not possible to conclude that $f'(x)$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a change of variables. With the definition $$\vec{p}=\hbar \vec{k} = \frac{h}{2\pi} \vec{k},$$
we can conclude that for every direction, $i\in\{x,y,z\}$
$$\frac{dk_i}{2\pi} = \frac{dp_i}{h}$$
therefore
$$\int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3} \rightarrow \int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{h^3}$$

the other factor is just volume $$V = \int d^3\vec{r}$$